# Error using enums as value in QMaps on windows

Tags: qt, enums, qmap

I have an application I wrote on OSX which works when complied on OSX but fails to compile on windows. In particular it gives me problems when I try to declare a QMap which has an enum as value. So when I try to do this:

```
QMap <QString, QPrinter::PaperSize> *avlbPaperSize = new QMap <QString, QPrinter::PaperSize>;
```

QtCreator gives me four errors:

```
invalid use of qualified-name 'QPrinter::PaperSize'
expected ';' at end of member declaration
expected unqualified-id before '>' token
wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
```

I can use int instead of QPrinter::PaperSize, but why do I get the error on windows and not on mac? Would using int and then casting it to the enum be a more correct way of doing this?
I use clang 64 on mac and mingw32 on windows

Comment: The error message suggests this is actually in-class initialization of member `avlbPaperSize`.  Have you specified at least `c++11` in the compiler options?  Although even if you haven't the error message is still a bit confusing.

Comment: I am in fact initializing avlbPaperSize in-class, and no I never specify c++11. However I restarted the computer and it doesn't give the error anymore.